# Jquery : Ajax is not been called first

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a Jquery code which looks like below

```
function get_data_obj(){
    var dataObj;
    $.ajax({
        url: "XXX.soesite.XXX",
        success: function(result) {
            dataObj = ['Hi'];
            console.log("Inside ajax");
            console.log(dataObj);
        }
    });
    console.log("Outside ajax");
    console.log(dataObj);
}
get_data_obj();
```

The output I am expecting is

> Inside ajax
>   ['Hi']
>   Outside ajax
>   ['Hi']

But the output I am getting looks like this

> Outside ajax
>   undefined
>   Inside ajax
>   ['Hi']

I am really confused about the control flow of my function. Basically, my function was supposed ajax first and then print the other statements but unfortunately my function is not working as expected by me. Can anybody please tell me what's wrong in my code and how can I make my function to finish off ajax work first and then go further?

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous, it'll print when it gets a response. Imagine it like a function call that will return a value whenever it's done but it does not interrupt the flow the original function that called it. Also, try `async:false` - this should do what you want. Remember, this is more of `being aware of something, but not using it.`

Comment: Thanks @MageshKumaar for the help. It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.ajax` is asynchronous be default if you don't specify otherwise.

if you want an operation to happen after the `$.ajax` request then you should include it in the `done()`/`success()`/`fail()` functions or set `async` to `false`.

```
function get_data_obj() {
    var dataObj;

    $.ajax({ url: "XXX.soesite.XXX", async: false, success: function(result) {
        dataObj = ['Hi'];
        console.log("Inside ajax");
        console.log(dataObj);
    }});

    console.log("Outside ajax");
    console.log(dataObj);
}

get_data_obj();
```

Comment: @ChiyaanSuraj Note that synchronous calls are depreciated and you are not advised to use the above solution.

Comment: @MageshKumaar - that's why my 1st suggestion is to call the next part of code in the `done()` state of the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

Please remember below when call ajax

Async:False(Default) = Codes paused. (Other codes are waiting for this..)

Async:True = Codes run parallel. Nothing get paused.

So jquery does not wait to complete the request first.

You can use the callback hooks provided by $.ajax()